# Manipulating array results in segfault?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a C application which involves parsing a text file (in a format called *VSM*, hence the names below) into a tree structure. The designer of the format calls it a *tagged tree*. Each node has some key-value pairs (or *attributes*) and child nodes.

Below are the struct and function in question:

vsm.h:

```
struct vsm_node {
    int                   numchildren;
    struct vsm_attribute *attrs   [36];
    struct vsm_node      *children[8];
};

void vsm_addchild(struct vsm_node *node, struct vsm_node *child);
```

vsm.c:

```
#include "vsm.h"

void vsm_addchild(struct vsm_node *node, struct vsm_node *child)
{
    node->children[node->numchildren] = child;
    ++(node->numchildren);
}
```

Why is it that when I call `vsm_addchild` it produces a segfault?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I just really suck at plain C. Especially if it has to do with pointers and memory management.

---

**EDIT** to include the code to make the call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vsm.h"

void vsm_parse(struct vsm_node *tree, FILE *fp, char *name)
{
    struct vsm_node *this     = tree;

    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != 0) {
        ...
        else if (ch == '{') {
            struct vsm_node *node;
            vsm_initnode(node);
            vsm_addchild(this, node);
            this = node;
            ...
        ...
```

---

**EDIT**: Added the `vsm_initnode` function, but I don't know if I'm doing it right.

```
void vsm_initnode(struct vsm_node *node)
{
    node              = malloc(     sizeof(struct vsm_node *));
    node->attrs       = malloc(36 * sizeof(struct vsm_attribute *));
    node->children    = malloc( 8 * sizeof(struct vsm_node *));
    node->numchildren = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 36; ++i)
        node->attrs[i] = NULL; /* unnecessary? */
    for (i = 0; i  < 8; ++i)
        node->children[i] = NULL;
}

void vsm_addchild(struct vsm_node *node, struct vsm_node *child)
{
    node->children[node->numchildren] = child;
    ++(node->numchildren);
}
```

gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
vsm_addchild (node=0x28, child=0x7541612d <msvcrt!_atodbl_l+2294>) at vsm.c:62
62              node->children[node->numchildren] = child;
```

Comment: And what's the code you are using to call `vsm_addchild`?

Comment: Edited my post to include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your node pointers incorrectly. This means that the `node` variable you are passing around is invalid and points randomly into memory, almost certainly into memory that your process does not own, causing a segmentation fault. Try this instead:

```
// Change (1): new return type, parameter removed
struct vsm_node* vsm_initnode()
{
    struct vsm_node* node;
    node              = malloc(     sizeof(struct vsm_node)); // Change (2)

    // The following lines are unnecessary - change (3)
    //node->attrs       = malloc(36 * sizeof(struct vsm_attribute *));
    // node->children    = malloc( 8 * sizeof(struct vsm_node *));

    node->numchildren = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 36; ++i)
        node->attrs[i] = NULL; // unnecessary but good practice
    for (i = 0; i  < 8; ++i)
        node->children[i] = NULL;

    return node;
}

void vsm_addchild(struct vsm_node *node, struct vsm_node *child)
{
    node->children[node->numchildren] = child;
    ++(node->numchildren);
}
```

Explanations for each error:

(1) - You were initially passing `struct vsm_node*` as a parameter to the function. This allows you to modify whatever value that pointer refers to. However, while you can modify the pointer itself (as you were by a call to `malloc`), those changes *are not reflected in the caller*. All of your memory allocation and initialization was just wasted.

(2) - A pointer of type `struct vsm_node*` must point to memory large enough to hold a `struct vsm_node`. Instead, you previously were allocating enough memory to hold a `struct vsm_node*`, which is not nearly large enough. A good rule of thumb is that the right side of a `malloc` call should contain one less level of indirection than the left side. That is, if the variable you're assigning into has type `T**`, then the `sizeof` call inside of `malloc` should refer to type `T*`, and so on for any number of `*` characters.

(3) Your struct definition is as follows:

```
struct vsm_node {
    int                   numchildren;
    struct vsm_attribute *attrs   [36];
    struct vsm_node      *children[8];
};
```

This means that when you allocate a `struct vsm_node` object, whether by using `malloc` or by simply declaring a variable of type `struct vsm_node`, it already has enough memory for both of your arrays of pointers. Allocating more memory is not only unnecessary but wasteful. It can also cause your program to behave differently than it would if you simply used the arrays with allocating additional memory.

Comment: On (3), I forgot to remove those two lines, as I redeclared them as `struct vsm_attribute **` and `struct vsm_node **` respectively. This gets the +1. Thanks. However, in an issue unrelated to this one, I have another segfault: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x753fde59 in msvcrt!iswdigit () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll`

Answer (score 3):

Here are reasons this code might segfault:

1. node is NULL, uninitialized, pointing to freed memory, or
2. node->children is NULL, uninitialized, pointing to freed memory, or
3. node->numchildren is greater than the allocated size of node->children

Make sure the calling code:

1. Allocates node
2. allocates node->children
3. sets node->numchildren
4. passed in the right value for node

---

Looking at the calling code pasted...

<s>The calling code does not allocate node; it's an uninitialized pointer, which means it points to a random location in memory.</s>

Misread that code due to the naming.  The child passed down is an uninitialized pointer, but that won't case a segfault in the demonstrated code because it's never dereferenced.

The first time `{` is entered, it should work fine.  The second time it should segfault because `this = node` sets `this` to an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating memory for node in

```
vsm_initnode(struct vsm_node *node)
```

Here **node** is a local variable and the allocation you did for node is lost when your vsm_initnode() completes its execution and returns to its calling module. Sort of **Dangling pointer issue**. In order to retain the allocation, you have to work on **double pointer** or **return the memory address**.

Below you can find both(double pointer and return memory address) implementation.

```
void vsm_parse(struct vsm_node *tree, FILE *fp, char *name)
{
    struct vsm_node *this     = tree;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != 0) {
        ...
        else if (ch == '{') {
           // Creating a object pointer.
           struct vsm_node *node; 

           /**********************************/
          /* Double Pointer Implementation  */
         /**********************************/
          vsm_initnode_double_pointer(&node); 


          /******************************************/
         /*  Return Memory Address Implementation  */
        /******************************************/
         node=vsm_initnode_return_address(); 

         vsm_addchild(this, node);
         this = node;
        ...
    ...

// Double Pointer Implementation 
void vsm_initnode_double_pointer(struct vsm_node **node)
{
    *node=malloc(sizeof(struct vsm_node *));
    // No need to allocate memory for attrs, children because it has been declared as array. You can directly store the memory location values in it.
    (*node)->numchildren = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 36; ++i)
       (*node)->attrs[i] = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i  < 8; ++i)
       (*node)->children[i] = NULL;
}

// Return Memory Address Implementation
struct vsm_node * vsm_initnode_return_address()
{
    struct vsm_node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct vsm_node *));
    // No need to allocate memory for attrs, children because it has been declared as array. You can directly store the memory location values in it.
    temp->numchildren = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 36; ++i)
       temp->attrs[i] = NULL; 
    for (i = 0; i  < 8; ++i)
       temp->children[i] = NULL;
return temp
}
```